# ConverterParameter Usage

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a basic question regarding the usage of ConverterParameter. In the sense - I can always create a collection of types in my viewmodel and pass it to the converter during Binding.

And then in my convert method - I can do multiple if check statements and return accordingly

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{

}
```

So the question is what exactly are the scenarios of using a ConverterParameter which just justifies it usage.

Please note - I am not asking how to use a ConverterParameter - i have done that - more interested when to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some of the cases where I used Converter parameter

1. I have a converter used by many user controls each user control
   represents specific class type. I used converter parameter to hold
   the class type so I can control the conversion behavior based on the
   parameter type.
2. I have a converter that convert date to string. I used converter
   parameter to define if It's Departure date or arrival date to return
   single string in the required format

Comment: Thanks Sayed for the use-cases